# how do i loop through the response of an http request in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular, am using Angular 11, and having trouble doing an http request.
I have looked through pages of stack overflow posts and none have worked for me, even though some have similar questions.
I have an http request to a server to get json data, which the result comes back like this:

```
{
   "OleOleOle":3463,
   "Saitama":1,
   "SalsaMan":563,
   ...
}
```

I need to loop through the JSON and put each key value pair in an array as an object, with the key as the name and the value as the viewCount.

I have been trying to do it with this:

```
  getLiveStreams() {
    this.http.get<any>(this.server.url).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      data.forEach((stream: any) => console.log(stream))
    })
  }
```

But I get an error saying:

ERROR TypeError: data.forEach is not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response is object try to use `Object.keys(data).forEach((key: any) => console.log(key + ":" + data[key]))`

Comment: This worked perfectly! I do have one question though. When i take away the type parameter from get (get<any>), it doesnt allow me to do data[key]. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Yeah it gives me this error if i try it without the type: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'"

Answer (score 0):

you can use `for .. in`

```
for (const property in data) {
    console.log(`${property}: ${data[property]}`);
}
```

[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your response is an object and not an array. [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function is for iterating through an array which is why you're getting the error. Instead you can iterate through the key value pairs using a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop,

```
for (let key in data) {
    console.log(key, data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your response is interpreted as an object (as no array is declared in the JSON response). If you expect an array, you should change the way your endpoint returns the data (if you can).

Otherwise, you will have to loop over the properties of the response, for example by using a `for...in` loop ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)).

```
for (let property in data) {
  console.log(property);
  console.log(data[property]);
}
```